# How to calculate the length of UDP payload?

Tags: networking, udp

I am sending a payload **TESTING**. I am trying to calculate the checksum for the UDP header which requires UDP total length. UDP header length is 8 bytes. Can anyone explain me how to calculate the data length with the above given payload. I tried searching the internet but could not find the relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the payload is the length of the payload in bytes.  So a 7 byte payload could hold the ASCII string "TESTING".  You could add a NUL terminator and make it 8 bytes.